# Adicionei inputs dinamicamente, porém o original é deletado

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Criei um botão de adiconar mais campos ao meu formulário, porém o quando clico no botão "-"(remover) ele não só apaga os campos adicionais,com deveria ser, mais também o campo original.

Alguém sabe com resolver este problema?

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

    var max_fields = 10;
    var wrapper = $(".test");
    var add_button = $(".add_field");

    var x = 1;

    $(add_button).click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (x < max_fields) {
            x++;
            $(wrapper).append('<input type="text" class="form-control" id="clientURL" aria-describedby="clientUrl" placeholder="URL da aplicação" /><a href = "#" class= "remove_field"> - </a>');
        }

    });

    $(wrapper).on("click", ".remove_field", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('div').remove();
        x--;
    });



});
```

```html
                <div class="form-group">
                  <div class="test">
                    <div>
                      <label for="clientSecret">URL</label>
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="clientURL" aria-describedby="clientUrl" placeholder="URL da aplicação" />
                      <button class="add_field">+</button>
                      <small id="client" class="form-text text-muted">Preencha com uma Url válida.</small>
                    </div>
                  </div>

                </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pelo que vi no seu código, você não agrupou o *input* com o *botão* dentro da *div* que você quer excluir no evento *click*.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var max_fields = 10;
    var wrapper = $(".test");
    var add_button = $(".add_field");

    var x = 1;

    $(add_button).click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (x < max_fields) {
            x++;
            $(wrapper).append('<div class="novos_inputs" ><label>Nova URL:</label><input type="text" class="form-control" id="clientURL" aria-describedby="clientUrl" placeholder="URL da aplicação" /><a href = "#" class= "remove_field"> - </a></div>');
        }

    });

    $(wrapper).on("click", ".remove_field", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('div').remove();
        x--;
    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="col-lg-12">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                         <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="test">
                              <div>
                                <label for="clientSecret">URL</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="clientURL" aria-describedby="clientUrl" placeholder="URL da aplicação" />
                                <button class="add_field">+</button>
                                <small id="client" class="form-text text-muted">Preencha com uma Url válida.</small>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Fiz aqui como vc falou e rodou direitinho. Obrigado pela ajuda man !!!

Comment: Brother marca a resposta como ✔️ do lado esquerdo da resposta, abaixo das setas de votação.